# Dynamic checkboxes to send array to controller only sending first choice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a table of data created like so:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= form_tag push_to_products_path(product), :id => 
  'submit_products' do  %>
      <%= check_box_tag('send[]', product.sellersku) %>
  <% end %>
</td>
<td><%= product.title %></td>
<td><%= product.asin %></td>
<% end %>
</tr>
```

I created the nested form_tag because I have a button outside of the form that uses the checkbox data to send to my Product controller. This is the button code:

```
<div class="row pad_bottom col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
  <button type="submit" form="submit_products" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload" aria-hidden="true"></span> Push 
    Selected Products
  </button>
</div>
```

The checkboxes are correctly created in the view, but when I test only the first box has the sellersku value.. all the other checkboxes don't pass anything. They should also be passing the sellersku.

Pretty sure its my loop, just not sure what I did wrong??

Comment: There is only one `check_box_tag` per form. i think, you need to take your `form` outside the products loop. so that the form has the `sellerskus` for all products in an loop. then secondly you need to change your `push_to_products` action to work as collection rather than just for one product.

Comment: What would that code look like?

Comment: i added an answer, hopefully with less errors..

Answer (score 0):

Declare your form outside of the loop. Right now, you're looping through your `@products` and creating a form for each one.

```
<%= form_tag push_to_products_path, :id => 'submit_products' do %>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= check_box_tag('send[]', product.sellersku) %></td>
      <td><%= product.title %></td>
      <td><%= product.asin %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag("Push Selected Products") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The issue though is the submit button outside of the form now.. that was the rub really.. I'm trying to use Jquery to set off the button, but now that doesn't want to work!!!! @athar

Answer (score 0):

```
  <%= form_tag products_push_to_path, :id => 'submit_products' do  %>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= check_box_tag('send[]', product.sellersku) %>
        </td>
        <td><%= product.title %></td>
        <td><%= product.asin %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag "Push Selected Products" %> #replace this with glyphicon part
  <% end %>
```

routes.rb #assuming your action name is `push_to` with resources `products`

```
  resources :products do
    collection do 
      post 'push_to'
    end
  end
```

Comment: i was not notified as i guess you have commented to the answer. but what happens if you replace the  `<%= submit_tag "Push Selected Products" %>` with your structure of showing button. didn't that work.?  what is happening